# Reoccurring weekly billing that only a user can see, based on a schedule in another node

Tags: 7, users

I need to setup a timed event, weekly, that will create a node or "billable event" based on a given pricing schedule (values on another node) and based on a date in another field on a different content type.  And now if that wasn't confusing enough, I need for only the specific user to be able to see it.  I'm open to any ideas as I really have no idea where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest using these modules: 
https://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess (to restrict node access per role or per user)
https://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron (flexible cron jobs)

Create separate cron job with flexible schedule where you can put all you custom logic with related nodes.